# Decrypt the following message that was encrypted using: Caesar’s cipher: WHVWWRGDB

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Decrypt the following message that was encrypted using:
(a) Caesar’s cipher: WHVWWRGDB

I'm told to decrypt the message using Ceasar's cipher but they don't tell me the key shift so how in the world am I supposed to decrypt the message? Am I missing something obvious here? Any help would be great

Comment: Clearly the message is SDRSSNCZX. (echo WHVWWRGDB | tr A-Z WXYZA-V)

Comment: Lol what? No, it's Test Today

Comment: Just a joke :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't have to do any of that stuff, just read somewhere that ceaser cipher commonly uses shifts of $3$ and then i subtracted 3 from each and came up with the message **Test Today**

Answer (score 1):

A frequency analysis is quite likely to tell you very little with such a short message. The most efficient approach is simply to try the $25$ possible shifts: most of them will very quickly reveal themselves as impossible. Here are the first few:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
W&H&V&W&W&R&G&D&B\\
X&I&W\\
Y&J\\
Z&K\\
A&L&Z&A&A\\
B&M\\
C&N\\
D&O&C&D&D\\
\end{array}$$

You’ll get there much faster if you work backwards through the shifts, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do frequency analysis. For example W is the letter which appears the most in the ciphertext so perhaps it corresponds to the letter "e" in the plaintext. If this works then V must be replacement for...... if this doesn;t work then try another letter (see [frequency of letters in English alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency))

Comment: OPUFOPVHIMFUUFSTGPSUIJTUPXPSLJNBGSBJE.